# Find bipartite graph with properties

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

**Problem:** Find a bipartite graph such that

a) Each part of the graph has 15 vertices
b) Each vertex has a degree of at least 7
c) There is no matching of size 15.

How can I construct such graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that no matching of size 15 implies no perfect matching. Try to construct a graph that violates the condition in Hall's Marriage Theorem.